# failed due to the following error: 80070005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID `{5FF57840-5172-4482-9CA3-541C7878AE0F}` failed due to the following error: `80070005`.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID `{5FF57840-5172-4482-9CA3-541C7878AE0F}` failed due to the following error: `80070005`.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically `{MACHINE}\ASPNET` on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via `<identity impersonate="true"/>`, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically `IUSR_MACHINENAME`) or the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
>  Line 23:  public partial class Report_Agent_Commission : System.Web.UI.Page
>  Line 24:  {
>  Line 25:      ReportDocument obj = new ReportDocument();
>  Line 26:      CrystalClass CCobj = new CrystalClass();
>  Line 27:      static string repFile = string.Empty;
> ```
>
> Source File:
>   d:\inetpub\vhosts\impactwebclients.com\httpdocs\Report_Agent_Commission.aspx.cs
>
> Line: 25
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5FF57840-5172-4482-9CA3-541C7878AE0F} failed due to the following error: 80070005.]     CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor() +207    [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.]     CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor() +0     PBS.GUI.Report_Agent_Commission..ctor() in d:\inetpub\vhosts\impactwebclients.com\httpdocs\Report_Agent_Commission.aspx.cs:25     ASP.report_agent_commission_aspx..ctor() in c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9b53e041\44708862\App_Web_report_agent_commission.aspx

---

This problem I am getting when using crystal reports 2008 version 10.5.3700.0, if I comment/delete the crystal report content on that particular webpage it is working fine. When I place a crystal reportviewer in the current web page it is showing error

Can you please help me out from here

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in paragraph 3 of your question?

Answer (score 0):

i found a answer my self.. please place custom error mode on in webconfig
and check the error status number, 99% it gives error no :500 -- that is a internal server
error, on the server machine there is problem
problem may be they has to instal crystal reports runtime or else may be any other problem
so it is not on your coding part so raise a complaint to them after confirming 500 error

thanks all if it is usefull to anybody.. it would be great